# Serving static files with NGINX for UNICORN served app

Tags: nginx, unicorn

I've just set up a Sinatra app running on Unicorn and served through a socket by NGINX.

I'm trying to get NGINX to serve my static assets with this in my nginx config:

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.app.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default;
  server_name localhost;
  root /home/ubuntu/app;

  location ^~ /public/ {
    root /home/ubuntu/app;
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

But my unicorn logs are still showing that it is serving the files

```
[03/Oct/2014 19:25:05] "GET /javascript/map.js HTTP/1.0" 304 - 0.0016
[03/Oct/2014 19:25:05] "GET /javascript/geopo.js HTTP/1.0" 304 - 0.0030
[03/Oct/2014 19:25:05] "GET /images/logo.png HTTP/1.0" 304 - 0.0022
```

etc.

What am I missing?

Comment: This isn't a Ruby or Sinatra question. It's a nginx configuration issue, and really should be asked on [webmasters.se].

Comment: @theTinMan What about server fault? They don't even have a unicorn tag on Webmasters. I already posted on server fault but haven't gotten any responses so I'm trying here. There are a tonne of nginx config questions on Stack.

Comment: [sf] is for "for professional system and network administrators." That's sysadmins and network engineer types. While they might overlap with nginx configuration and management, [webmasters.se] is a lot bigger overlap. And, while [so] handles some application support for programming tools, nginx configuration isn't as closely related compared to things like vim, emacs, svn, git, etc. SO will have a larger number of Q/A for various topics, because it's been around longer. That the questions still exist don't make the same topics valid now. That's just how new special-interest sections start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to explicitly tell the web server to load those files via a `location` directive.

Here's an example for what I use with Unicorn to have the web server load assets:

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
  root /home/ubuntu/app/public;
  expires max;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
  log_not_found off;
}
```

Comment: I just tried this out and I think it's a good first step, because now no static files come through at all and my page is unstyled and un scripted. `directory index of "/home/ubuntu/app/" is forbidden` I'm guessing I might need to target the public folder somehow so that the files are actually found... any idea?

Comment: fix your answer to include these changes `        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
          root /home/ubuntu/app/public;
          expires max;
          log_not_found off;
          add_header Cache-Control public;
        }` and I will accept it. Thanks for the help